# R eurostat special value ' : ' in database

Tags: r

I have a problem with special values like ' : ' in the eurostat database:
https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=env_wasgen&lang=en
I cannot load them into R studio:
Iam using the R eurostat package to load data with the function get_eurostat() into R Studio:

```
    dat_wasgen <- get_eurostat("env_wasgen", time_format = "num")
```

So far this works well. 
But, there is a problem if the database has special values.
Special values appear in the dataexplorer like that ' : '

1. I checked the documentation of Eurostat package: 
   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eurostat/eurostat.pdf
   and decided to keep the flags. In hope that special values are part of the flags.
2. I checked the eurostat documentation, see  https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database/information . Here ' : ' are listed as special values, which means NA.

TRY 1:

```r
dat_wasgen <- get_eurostat("env_wasgen", time_format = "num", keepFlags = TRUE)
```

Result 1: No ' : ' in the flags column!

TRY 2:

```r
#load data
dat_wasgen <- get_eurostat("env_wasgen", time_format = "num", keepFlags = TRUE)

#define the labelvector and merge with datavector
dat2 <- label_eurostat(dat_wasgen)

#convert into dataframe
df <-as.data.frame(dat2)

#convert Na. values into 0
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Result 2: still no sucess! values ' : ' are not in the database! also not available as ' 0 ' and ' NA ' values.

For example I need the value of the following filter:

```r
#filter with waste = w91 + households
HH_w91 <- subset(df, geo == "European Union - 28 countries"
                 & time == 2014
                 & hazard == "Non-hazardous"
                 & nace_r2 == "Households" 
                 & unit == "Kilograms per capita"
                 & waste %in% c("Animal and mixed food waste")
)
```

in the eurostat database this value is defined as ' : '
and I need this value in my database defined with ' NA ', but there is just nothing visible! What can I do to get ' : ' as ' NA ' into my database?

Comment: Apparently `:` entries are not saved in the database.

Comment: @Roland data is saved in a long format in the database, but on website it is presented as aggergate+table format, and they used `":"` character when there is no data for X country in Y year, `":"` is just a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

We need to reformat the data to match with the websites aggregated results.

Data, we can see there are some NAs in *values* column:

```
library(eurostat)

dat_wasgen <- get_eurostat("env_wasgen", time_format = "num")
head(dat_wasgen)
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#   unit   hazard nace_r2 waste geo    time values
#   <fct>  <fct>  <fct>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  AT     2016     NA
# 2 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  BE     2016      2
# 3 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  BG     2016      0
# 4 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  CY     2016      1
# 5 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  CZ     2016      1
# 6 KG_HAB HAZ    A       PRIM  DE     2016      0
```

Aggregate to reproduce the table from the website

```
res <- aggregate(dat_wasgen$values, dat_wasgen[, c("geo", "time")], sum,  na.rm = TRUE)
```

Let's compare with the website for below example two countries:

```
# NO - Norway 2008 10,286,643
# RS - Serbia 2008 :
```

Reshape from long to wide, to match with website's format:

```
x <- dcast(res, geo ~ time)
```

Lookup RS and NO:

```
x[ x$geo %in% c("RS", "NO"), ]
#    geo      2004      2006      2008      2010      2012      2014      2016
# 27  NO 146438169 192271964 198994721 212405022 223984711 220607527 233496426
# 31  RS        NA        NA        NA 578802364 916005383 825635788 837163452
```

The numbers do not match, this could be due to we need to filter the data before aggregating. But we can see RS has no data for 2008.

Comment: @JessicaRjes data is saved in a long format in the database, but on website it is presented as aggergate+table format, and they used `":"` character when there is no data for X country in Y year, `":"` is just a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to solve the problem with ' :' in the database: It is the classic way to load the database as csv from the homepage, but the NA values are now correct:

1. Step: Download data in csv from https://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/show.do?dataset=env_wasgen&lang=en

```r
#read csv into R
df_raw<-read.csv("env_wasgen_data_fil.csv")

#define NA values
library (dplyr)
df<- df_raw %>% dplyr::na_if(":")
str(df)

#set column from factor to numeric
df$Value=as.numeric(df$Value)
str(df)
df$TIME=as.numeric(df$TIME)
```